# How to read first N lines of a text file and write it to another text file?

Tags: python, lines

Here is the code I modified from previous code.
But, I got this error:

```
TypeError: must be str not list in f1.write(head)
```

This is the part of code that is producing this error:

```
from itertools import islice
with open("input.txt") as myfile:
    head = list(islice(myfile, 3))
f1.write(head)

f1.close()
```

Comment: where did you declare

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you have it right, using `islice(filename, n)` will get you the first `n` lines of file `filename`. The problem here is when you try and write these lines to another file.

The error is pretty intuitive (I've added the full error one receives in this case):

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list
```

This is because **[`f.write()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write)** accepts strings as parameters, not `list` types.

So, instead of dumping the list as is, write the contents of it in your other file using a `for` loop:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as myfile:
    head = list(islice(myfile, 3))

# always remember, use files in a with statement
with open("output.txt", "w") as f2:
    for item in head:
        f2.write(item)
```

Granted that the contents of the list are **all** of type `str` this works like a charm; if not, you just need to wrap each `item` in the `for` loop in an **[`str()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str)** call to make sure it is converted to a string.

If you want an approach that doesn't require a loop, *you could always consider* using **[`f.writelines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.writelines)** instead of `f.write()` (and, take a look at Jon's comment for another tip with `writelines`).

Comment: Note: you've mis-spelt `islice` (first example) - and instead of creating a `list`, then using: `f2.writelines(islice(myfile, 3))` will work fine...